# Right adjoint of the pullback functor in comma category of topological spaces

Tags: ct.category-theory

Consider the category **TOP** of topological spaces. A morphism $s :
X \rightarrow B$ is said to be exponentiable in **TOP** if $(X, s)$ is an exponentiable
object in **TOP/B**, i.e. the functor $(-)$ x $(X, s)$ has a right adjoint. Please
give explicit discription of right adjoint functor of the fuctor $(-)$ x $(X, s)$.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: I doubt it's homework. But it's not really clear how to pitch an answer, since no background information is given. @Hina: please click on "how to ask" above. A good MO question will generally indicate what thinking the poster has done on the problem, where the difficulty seems to lie, and (it would be nice) why the interest. For example, I don't know if you know what the underlying sets are of the exponentials you are asking about. 

Answer (score 7):

Since you don't indicate what you know and what you don't know about this problem, I'll simply refer you to the work of Susan Niefield. You can start reading [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n2/8-02abs.html), and consult the references therein, particularly

- S. B. Niefield, Cartesianness, topological spaces, uniform spaces, and affine schemes, J. Pure Appl. Alg. 23, 1982, 147–167.

where she extends the Day-Kelley characterization of exponentiable objects in $Top$ to slice categories $Top/B$. Much of this is phrased in the language of continuous lattices.